# Is the Santa Clarita Diet virus only bloodbourne?

Tags: plot-explanation, santa-clarita-diet

In the show it is implied many many times that Joel and Sheila are still sexually active after Sheila's transformation.  However in the final episode of Season 1 it is feared that Sheila broke Joel's skin with a bite during their latest encounter - possibly passing the "infection" to him as she did with Anton.

Is it safe to assume that whatever infected Sheila is only a bloodbourne "illness" considering all the fluid exchanges that still occur between the couple?

Comment: I should also note I'm far from a medical professional when it comes to disease transmission....

Comment: Seems that this is the *implication* but... https://www.bustle.com/p/how-does-the-zombie-virus-work-in-santa-clarita-diet-the-undead-life-is-very-mysterious-34894

Answer (score 2):

Actually in the final episode, Sheila bites Joel, but later when they talked about this incident with Dr. Cora Wolf, and Dr.Cora asks her if she broke his skin, she says no.

We know that if Sheila bites someone, the person turns into a zombie, but **We are never really explained who the virus fully works in the series**.

> Sheila does wonder if she could have gotten it from the clams that she ate at the restaurant Japopo's. Getting the virus from shellfish would be a twist on [zombie folklore](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20150828-where-do-zombies-come-from), but that reference could be more of a sex joke than a plot point.

According to [this source](http://www.thisisinsider.com/santa-clarita-diet-zombie-virus-2017-2):

> In the season one finale, Dr. Wolf (Portia de Rossi) offers a few suggestions including a mutation of the rabies virus or a resurgence of an ancient plague, but she said speculation was pointless.
>
> Eric suggests in the premiere that most new viruses come from animals such as monkeys or bats.

We just have to wait until season 2 comes out and explains a little bit more =)

Comment: In a way I kinda wish the canon explanation is the Japopo's clams because it sounds funny.